# next js Component Scroll Behavior Issue.Facing trouble achieving desired scroll behavior based on isSelectedImageIndex in my Next js component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, scroll, scrollview

The provided code is a Next js component named Image Generation responsible for rendering images based on certain conditions. It utilizes a useRef to potentially scroll into view.

The component includes conditional rendering logic based on initial Load, loading, and the length of response Data Images. It displays either a generated image, a skeleton loader, or a message when there's no data.

The primary concern is that scrolling into view using scroll Into View doesn't work as expected. The intention is to scroll only when isSelectedImageIndex becomes true, especially when displaying a skeleton loader.

```
      const responseDataImagesRef = useRef<any>(null);
  responseDataImagesRef.current?.scrollIntoView(false);

  return (
     <Flex
          className="hide-scrollbar"
          w={"70vw"}
          mx={"auto"}
          justify={"center"}
          overflowY={"auto"}
          ref={responseDataImagesRef}
        >
          <Grid
            mt={"5.7vh"}
            templateColumns={`repeat(${maxResponseDataColumns}, 1fr)`}
            gap={"12px"}
          >
            {props.responseDataImages?.[
              props.latestGeneratedImagesIndex != null
                ? props.latestGeneratedImagesIndex
                : props.responseDataImages.length - 1
            ].images?.map((images: any, index: number) => {
              const isSelectedImageIndex = index === props.selectedImageIndex;
              return (
                <GridItem key={index}>
                  {isSelectedImageIndex ? (
                    <GridItem
                      borderRadius="20px"
                     
                      maxH={"500px"}
                      p={"15px"}
                      border="1px solid #303030"
                      background="rgba(25, 19, 36, 0.70)"
                    >
                      <Skeleton
                        w={"100%"}
                        h={`100%`}
                        maxH={"500px"}
                        borderRadius="20px"
                        startColor="#3D3E41"
                        endColor="#2B2C2F"
                      />
                    </GridItem>
                  ) : (
                    <Stack
                      className="container"
                     
                      maxH={"500px"}
                      pos={"relative"}
                      borderRadius="20px"
                      border="1px solid #303030"
                      background="rgba(25, 19, 36, 0.70)"
                    >
                      <Image
                        className="image"
                        src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${images.imgSrc}`}
                        objectFit={"cover"}
                        borderRadius={"10px"}
                        mx={"auto"}
                        
                        p={"15px"}
                        maxH={"500px"}
                        alt="generated image"
                      />
                      <Box className="middle" w={"100%"} height={"100%"}>
                        <Flex
                          transition="opacity 0.3s ease-in-out"
                          pos={"absolute"}
                          bottom={"15px"}
                          left={"15px"}
                        >
                          <Menu>
                            <MenuButton
                              px={0}
                              bg={"none"}
                              _hover={{
                                bg: "none",
                              }}
                              _active={{
                                bg: "none",
                              }}
                              border={"1px solid rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.2)"}
                              color={"white"}
                              as={Button}
                            >
                              <Flex align={"center"} justify={"center"}>
                                <Image
                                  objectFit={"cover"}
                                  src={AllImages.magicEdit.src}
                                  alt="magic"
                                />
                              </Flex>
                            </MenuButton>
                            <MenuList
                              className="aspectRatio-background"
                              backdropFilter={"blur(50px) brightness(4)"}
                              border={"0.2px solid rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.2)"}
                              color={"white"}
                              fontSize={"12px"}
                              fontFamily={"poppins"}
                              fontWeight={500}
                            >
                              <MenuItem
                                bg={"none"}
                                onClick={() =>
                                  props.handleUpscale(
                                    images.imgSrc,
                                    "latest Images",
                                    index
                                  )
                                }
                              >
                                Upscale
                              </MenuItem>
                              <MenuItem
                                bg={"none"}
                                onClick={() =>
                                  props.ClarifyHandsInImage(
                                    "latest Images",
                                    index,
                                    images.infoSeedValue
                                  )
                                }
                              >
                                Hand Restore
                              </MenuItem>
                              <MenuItem
                                bg={"none"}
                                onClick={() =>
                                  props.faceStore(
                                    "latest Images",
                                    index,
                                    images.infoSeedValue
                                  )
                                }
                              >
                                Face Restore
                              </MenuItem>
                            </MenuList>
                          </Menu>
                        </Flex>
                        <Button
                          bg={"none"}
                          _hover={{
                            bg: "none",
                          }}
                          _active={{
                            bg: "none",
                          }}
                          border={"1px solid rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.2)"}
                          pos={"absolute"}
                          top={"15px"}
                          right={"15px"}
                          px={0}
                          color={"white"}
                          onClick={() => props.onImageGenerated(images.imgSrc)}
                        >
                          <Flex align={"center"}>
                            <Image
                              objectFit={"cover"}
                              src={AllImages.downloadHd.src}
                              alt="download"
                            />
                          </Flex>
                        </Button>
                      </Box>
                    </Stack>
                  )}
                </GridItem>
              );
            })}
            {props.artGen && props.loading && (
              <GridItem
                borderRadius="20px"
                p={"15px"}
                minH={"432px"}
                border="1px solid #303030"
                background="rgba(25, 19, 36, 0.70)"
              >
                <Skeleton
                  w={"100%"}
                  h={"100%"}
                  startColor="#3D3E41"
                  endColor="#2B2C2F"
                />
              </GridItem>
            )}
          </Grid>
        </Flex>
  )
```